# executing PL/PGSQL blocks using python without storing them into database

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Am working to build Django application using python, the application is expected to receive large volume of data, I've worked on some PL/PGSQL procedures that can enhance the performance. Those procedures are stored in files and I don't want to create them on the database.

I only want to be able to execute them using postgresql_psycopg2 another tricky part is that I want to be able to change some parameter in the files prior to execution which am not sure how to deal with it.

Here is my Python code

```
        pg_script = os.path.join(getattr(settings, 'BASE_DIR'),'myapp/apps/rating/sql/rating_create_article_rating.sql')

        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("run script %s" % pg_script)
```

Here is rating_create_article_rating.sql

```
DECLARE
    article_rec   publication_article%ROWTYPE;
    user_rec      auth_user%ROWTYPE;
    up            integer := 1;
    down          integer := -1;
    l_counter     integer := 0; -- local counter
    cnt           integer;
    p_content_type_id integer;
BEGIN



    LOOP
        -- RANDOM ARTICLE
        SELECT *
        INTO article_rec
        FROM publication_article
        order by random()
        LIMIT  1;

        -- RANDOM USER
        SELECT *
        INTO user_rec
        FROM auth_user
        order by random()
        LIMIT  1;

        BEGIN
          INSERT INTO rating_rate (rated_by_id, rated_at, content_type_id, object_id, rate, language)
          VALUES (user_rec.id, now(), p_content_type_id, article_rec.id, 1, 'en');
          l_counter := l_counter+1;
        EXCEPTION
              WHEN unique_violation THEN

        END;



        EXIT WHEN l_counter>cnt;
    END LOOP;


    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the code above works when i execute it as a stored function, otherwise with the run script its not working, am getting the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "run" at character 1
STATEMENT:  run script /Users/mo/Projects/pythonic/myapp-env/myapp/myapp/apps/rating/sql/rating_create_article_rating.sql
```

am also wondering if there is a way to pass a parameter to file and handle it from pl/pgsql?

many thanks

Comment: You can use anonymous functions. `DO $$ -- Code $$;`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html

Comment: when using anonymous functions, do i reference the script location or do i read the script content and dump it in the cursor?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just put the procedure in the database and call it. It should be faster that way I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I prefer to put these things in functions.  One important reason is that this helps separate sql and application code, making it easier to read and find what you need.  There are also some optimizations that can happen with functions.

If this is not sufficient, use a DO block.  DO blocks have a number of important limitations though.  They cannot return results, for example.  This means that if you want to return useful information regarding inserts or the like, you can't do that.

`DO` creates an anonymous function without a return type.  You would encompass your function body in the `DO LANGUAGE PLPGSQL $$ .. $$;` block and it will run immediately.